# Create a pool for each parallel process

Tags: python, parallel-processing, pool

I'm working on a code that iteratively fits a model consisting of `ncomp` components. Each component is fit with `emcee`. I would like to fit components in parallel, and I would like to parallelise `emcee` as well. The idea is that each process creates its own pool for `emcee`. What is the best way to do that?
I figured that I should probably use `MPIPoolExecutor` and `spawn` but couldn't find any clear and simple examples at the beginner level.
I'm running the code on a cluster.

This is a simplified version:

```
import numpy as np
from mpi4py import MPI

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
size=comm.Get_size()
rank=comm.Get_rank()

if rank == 0:
    # Init
    naivefit = NaiveFit()
    naivefit.first_run_fit()

    # SPLIT DATA into multiple processes
    ncomps = len(naivefit.prev_result['comps'])
    comps = np.array_split(range(ncomps), size)
else:
    naivefit = None
    comps = None

while True:
    # BROADCAST CONSTANTS
    naivefit = comm.bcast(naivefit, root=0)  # updated params

    # SCATTER DATA
    comps = comm.scatter(comps, root=0)

    # Create a pool here for each process... Perhaps it would be better to
    # create it outside the `while` loop?
    pool=???

    # FIT
    all_results_rank = []
    for comp in comps:
        result = naivefit.fit_using_emcee(i=comp, pool=pool)
        all_results_rank.append(result)

    # GATHER DATA AND UPDATE NAIVEFIT
    all_results_tmp = comm.gather(all_results_rank, root=0)
    if rank == 0:
        all_results = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(all_results_tmp))

        # 'terminate' tells the loop to terminate if the fit converged.
        terminate = naivefit.run_fit_gather_results_multiproc(all_results)

        # Within naivefit: ncomps=ncomps+1. 
        # Now update ncomps and comps in the code.
        ncomps = len(naivefit.prev_result['comps'])
        comps = np.array_split(range(ncomps), size)
    else:
        terminate=None
        naivefit=None
        comps=None

    terminate = comm.bcast(terminate, root=0)

    if terminate:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

I would rather launch the program with NxP process and create N subcommunicator of size P with MPI_Comm_split() (don't now the python binding, maybe comm.split() ?).
Then use this communicator inside fit_using_emcee() which needs to be implemented using MPI also.
I don't use spawning because I don't know how the job scheduler on clusters is allowing it.